# How to send a c# event to the working lua script?

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

i'm using c# and LuaInterface and i need to send an event from my c# code to the working script. For example, it may be a button_click that interrupts working lua script or chanhes its logic. So, how can i do something like this?

Comment: you can't interrupt a Lua script; the script can use coroutine to temporarily yield control back to the application but it is still not "interrupting".

Comment: There's no reason this question should be on hold. A callback is not an unusual concept.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be on hold at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You either require the Lua script to create a global function, which you call by name when the event occurs, or you register a function in C# which the Lua code calls to register a callback. The latter is a lot more flexible.

```
    private void Test()
    {
        lua.RegisterFunction("setEventHandler", this, GetType().GetMethod("SetEventHandler"));
        lua.DoString(@"
            setEventHandler( 
                function(arg) 
                    print('In my event handler:', arg) 
                end)
        ");
        CallEventHandler("This is an event!");
    }

    public delegate void EventHandler(String s);

    private EventHandler _eventHandler;

    public void SetEventHandler(EventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        _eventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    public void CallEventHandler(string test )
    {
        _eventHandler(test);
    }
```